# .htaccess with python scripts

Tags: python, apache, .htaccess, web-applications

n00b question. 
I have an .htaccess file with the following :

```
AddHandler python-program .py
PythonHandler index
```

I try to write another program named script2.py but when I type it fileserver/script2.py it redirects to fileserver/index.py. Any way to stop this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are different ways to configure mod_python. I think you want [python.publisher](http://www.modpython.org/live/mod_python-2.7.8/doc-html/tut-pub.html). The docs show this config:

```
AddHandler python-program .py
PythonHandler mod_python.publisher
```

Then, for your example, script2.py would have something like:

```
def index(req):
    # Your handler here
```

Note, the documentation says:

> This handler allows access to functions and variables within a module via URL's.

The documentation provides this example (which I've changed to use script2.py):

```
def say(req, what="NOTHING"):
    return "I am saying %s" % what
```

> A URL http://www.mysite.com/script2.py/say would return "I am saying NOTHING". A URL http://www.mysite.com/hello.py/say?what=hello would return "I am saying hello".

Usually you don't want to expose every function and variable.

> The traversal will stop and HTTP_NOTFOUND will be returned to the client if:
>
> - Any of the traversed object's names begin with an underscore ("_"). Use underscores to protect objects that should not be accessible from the web.